# How to set each line from text file to a string variable?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to line up the text in text file.

This is to line up and display each line for the text file. I've tried my own batch program. But its failed.

**`file.txt` contains,**

```
Rabbit
Cat
Dog
Cow
Pig
```

**`test.bat` contains,**

```
@echo off
cls
for /f "skip=1 tokens=*" %%a In (file.txt) do set "str=%%a" & goto next
:next
echo %str%
pause>nul
```

**Expected output in cmd window when running `test.bat`**

```
Rabbit
Cat
Dog
Cow
Pig
```

**But the actual output am getting in cmd window,**

```
Cat
```

Comment: The command you have written should output the information you have shown us. Open a Command Prompt window and enter `for /?` to read the usage information for the command you are having an issue with.

Comment: That's because you break the loop after the first line with `goto`. Try `for /f "skip=1 tokens=*" %%a In (file.txt) do echo %%a`

Comment: If you were wanting the first line, _(not beginning with a semicolon)_, there's also no need to use `Skip`.

Comment: That works and its displaying the output. But, Actually i want to display like, 

`echo 1 - %var1%
echo 2 - %var2%
echo 3 - %var3%
echo 4 - %var4%
echo 5 - %var5%`

each line in different varible. Kindly help me to set this up.

Comment: So you basically want to have array-like variables, hence you should take a look at [this great post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10167990)...

Answer (score 2):

implement a counter and use it to generate the variable names like `str[1]`...:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set counter=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%a In (file.txt) do (
  set /a counter+=1
  set "str[!counter!]=%%a"
)
set str[
```